# How do I associate Drupal menu items to regions? (I'm creating a mega menu)

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-7, megamenu

My site is runnning Drupal 7.x, however I would like to know the best approach to create mega-menus (like the one in the screenshot below) without installing extra modules. I'm a developer but I don't have much experience with Drupal.

Honestly I don't care if I have to create manually many regions or blocks as links on the main menu as long as I can bind them. Is there any way of doing this? Maybe adding a extra field (perhaps a select with a list of regions) on [http://mysite.example.com/admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu -> Menu item] could do the trick ?

Please let me know if my option is a dead end, I'm open to any solution.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Mega menu sample]

Comment: There are probably a few ways you could do this but why reinvent the wheel? Why don't you want to install a module for this?

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, this feature I have never thought, but did you try with 'title callback' and 'title arguments' ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add all those links in the main-menu menu, changing orders, parents and so on ?

And then with https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu css them?

If do not want to install a module like tb_megamenu then you have to add css by hand

All menu elements in drupal are rendered in ul>li with first class, last class, odd even class, menuid, active trail and so on